# Is it possible to access order meta or post meta from gettext filter

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am using `gettext` filter to change one of the text in email. I want to access one of the value using `get_post_meta`. But i need $order_id to use `get_post_meta`. But `$order` and `$order_id` is undefined on `var_dump`.

```
function custom_review_strings( $translated_text, $text, $domain ) {
  $substr = 'You have received an order from';
  if (strpos($translated_text, $substr) !== false) {
     /* use get_post_meta value to do some task here */
  }
  return $translated_text;
}
add_filter( 'gettext', 'custom_review_strings', 20, 3 );
```

Comment: you can't pass the order id  in the `gettext` hook instead you can use another hook to check your condition and if true you can fire the `gettext`, if you can explain exactly what you are looking to do we might be able to help more

Comment: @kashalo Thank you. That was sufficient. I already written code as checking `order id` in another hook and firing `gettext` if present.